# Creating a container that runs IBM Containers Extension (ICE)

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to create container from which I will be able to create dockers on bluemix (on demand)
I tried to follow instructions described on this page
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ice_ov.html#container_cli_ice_dockerfile

Once I perform this command:
"docker build -t image_name:tag dockerfile_location"

I get error on step 5:

---

```
Step 5 : RUN wget "ttps://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&version=6.12&source=github-rel" --output-document=cf.tgz && tar -xvf cf.tgz  && mv cf /usr/bin/cf
 ---> Running in 42dbf6ca5f4d
--2015-11-09 13:14:17--  ttps://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&version=6.12&source=github-rel
Resolving cli.run.pivotal.io (cli.run.pivotal.io)... 52.2.163.125, 52.21.135.158
Connecting to cli.run.pivotal.io (cli.run.pivotal.io)|52.2.163.125|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 412 Precondition Failed
2015-11-09 13:14:18 ERROR 412: Precondition Failed.
```

---

Any help with that will be very appreciated

Comment: Looks like you're just missing an 'h' somewhere...

Comment: I just removed the "h' from original error message since stackoverflow doesn't allow new users to post more than 2 links in the post ....

Answer (score 1):

It seems that version 6.12 is not a correct parameter anymore to download the stable cf cli. You can try the latest 6.12 version (6.12.4) by using:

```
wget "https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&version=6.12.4&source=github-rel"
```

The list of stable releases being pulled down is [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases)

Comment: I have opened a work item to have the documentation reviewed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, with 6.12.4 script works fine. 

I will use this topic for another question:

When performing ice login (to stage1 for IBM'ers) - I get following error:
 ---------------------------------
 Error response from daemon: Login: You must set a namespace before you login to the registry. 
 ---------------------------------
I have namespace 'dev' defined (at least i can observe it using console). I've tried also to create another namespace and specify them using --space command.
In both cases I get same error.

Any clue what I'm missing here ?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @YevgeniBurshtein this should probably be another question, but have you tried calling `ice namespace set` I would be surprised that your namespace is called dev. Are you sure that you are not confusing a Bluemix space with an ICE namespace?

Comment: Hi , thanks for replay!
I will post this as another question